# what is the handwritten notation for a random vector?

Tags: notation, vectors

Not sure if this is a maths question but didn't know where to turn. I'm learning probability theory on my own using a textbook. 
It uses capital letters with subscripted number to denote random variables (eg, X1,...,Xn) and bold subscripted capital letters (eg, **X1**,...,**Xn**) for random vectors. 
What's the convention for representing the latter in handwritten notes?
thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe $\vec{X_i}$

Comment: Putting an arrow above the symbol is the usual convention for handwritten text, but it's really not necessary to use any special notation for vectors versus scalars.

Comment: In statistics (or mathematics), it is not necessary to make boldface to represent vectors as in physics or engineering. Just put $X$ is fine, if the context is clear.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what $\mathbb{X}$ is for?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: I don't know about engineering, but it's not done in physics (at least at the professional level) either. I don't know whether the arrow is _completely_ unheard of, the way it is in math (see also the $\div$ symbol), but it's definitely not necessary or encouraged.

Comment: thanks all for your very prompt responses.

Answer (score 1):

I teach in my physics class that vectors are shown in textbooks by boldface but are shown in handwriting by adding the vector symbol over the variable. So,

$$\mathbf {X_n}=\overrightarrow {X_n}$$